# Commutant of set of matrices

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to compute the commutant of a set of matrices, so the set of matrices that commutes with all matrices in the original set.

I'm a complete newbie with mathematica, so I would be greatful for help.

In principle I thought it should be possible to define a matrix of variables `M` and then use `M.B-B.M==0` for every `B` in my set of matrices to build a large set of equations which mathematica should be able to solve to obtain a basis for `M`. However, I am not quite sure how to execute it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a random matrix:

```
n = 3;
M = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {n, n}]
(*    {{9, 1, 8},
       {-7, 8, -3},
       {7, 10, -7}}    *)
```

Build a matrix of unknowns:

```
B = Array[b, {n, n}]
vars = Flatten[B]

(*    {{b[1, 1], b[1, 2], b[1, 3]},
       {b[2, 1], b[2, 2], b[2, 3]},
       {b[3, 1], b[3, 2], b[3, 3]}}    *)

(*    {b[1, 1], b[1, 2], b[1, 3], b[2, 1], b[2, 2], b[2, 3], b[3, 1], b[3, 2], b[3, 3]}    *)
```

Build the equations for $B$ in matrix form, and look for the null space:

```
s = NullSpace[D[Flatten[M . B - B . M], {vars}]]
(*    {{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
       {183, 105, 77, -196, 72, -83, 0, 97, 0},
       {-278, -953, 6, 1281, 735, 539, 679, 0, 0}}    *)
```

Arrange these solutions into $n\times n$ matrices:

```
q = Partition[#, n] & /@ s
(*    {{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}},
       {{183, 105, 77}, {-196,  72, -83}, {0, 97, 0}},
       {{-278, -953, 6}, {1281, 735, 539}, {679, 0, 0}}}    *)
```

Try if they commute with $M$:

```
M . # - # . M & /@ q
(*    {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
       {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
       {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}    *)
```

Build an arbitrary matrix that commutes with $M$:

```
qq = {α, β, γ} . q
(*    {{α + 183 β - 278 γ, 105 β - 953 γ, 77 β + 6 γ},
       {-196 β + 1281 γ, α + 72 β + 735 γ, -83 β + 539 γ},
       {679 γ, 97 β, α}}                                      *)

M . qq - qq . M // Expand
(*    {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}    *)
```

Alternatively, go straight for the `Solve` way:

```
Solve[Thread[Flatten[M . B - B . M] == 0]]
(*    {{b[2, 1] -> -(147/109) b[1, 2] - 77/109 b[1, 3],
        b[2, 2] -> b[1, 1] - 811/763 b[1, 2] + 6/763 b[1, 3],
        b[2, 3] -> -(433/763) b[1, 2] - 232/763 b[1, 3],
        b[3, 1] -> -(77/109) b[1, 2] + 105/109 b[1, 3],
        b[3, 2] -> 6/763 b[1, 2] + 953/763 b[1, 3],
        b[3, 3] -> b[1, 1] - 232/763 b[1, 2] - 1497/763 b[1, 3]}}    *)
```